# Thymeleaf - tag inside th:text

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I need to put  tag or text based on some expression. I tried an expression like this bud didn't work.

```
<td th:text="${reservation[0] == null ? <a href="/reserve">Reserve</a> : reservation[0] == request.username ? <a href="/cancel">Cancel</a> : Reserved}"></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<td th:utext="${reservation[0] == null} ? '<a href="/reserve">Reserve</a>' :  ${reservation[0] == request.username} ? '<a href="/cancel">Cancel</a>' : 'Reserved'"></td>
```

You can also make it easier to read with multiple test conditions:

```
<td th:if="${reservation[0] == null}"><a href="/reserve">Reserve</a></td>
<td th:if="${reservation[0] == request.username}"><a href="/cancel">Cancel</a></td>
```

If the condition is not fullfilled then th  tag is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The Thymeleaf [switch statement](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#switch-statements) provides a clean alternative:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    <th:block th:switch="${reservation[0]}">
        <td><a th:case="null" th:text="Reserve" href="/reserve"></a><td>
        <td><a th:case="${request.username}" th:text="Cancel" href="/cancel"></a><td>
        <td th:case="*" th:text="'Reserved'"></td>
    </th:block>
    </tr>
</table>
```